# 24 iteration javascript loop shows 10 canvas only

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'd like to generate 24 canvas but there's only 10 showing up on the page. 
I cannot use the whole width and cannot really figure out why. 
Here's a snippet of code to illustrate my example: https://jsfiddle.net/bLr83jyn/2/

```js
var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'purple'];

function MakeCanvas(x, y, w, h, color) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var w = 30;
var h = w * 1.5;
var offset = w;

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  MakeCanvas(x, y, w, h, colors[i % colors.length]);
  x = x + offset;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I changed w to 10 to test and 24 show up now. Do the math...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a size for the canvas, so its using the default size of 300 x 150. So by the time you've rendered 10 of the rectangles, you've used up all 300 px of width, and all the rest are drawn outside the bounds of the canvas

If you want a larger canvas, you can add properties to the canvas element. For example:

```js
var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'purple'];

function MakeCanvas(x, y, w, h, color) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var w = 30;
var h = w * 1.5;
var offset = w;

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  MakeCanvas(x, y, w, h, colors[i % colors.length]);
  x = x + offset;
}
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

That one will let you fit 20 of the 30px wide rectangles before you run out of space. Alternatively, you could render smaller rectangles. Just depends on what you're trying to do.